# International Ordering

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, internationalization

With our current shopping cart system, we use a service called, "BorderFree" to handle all of our international orders.  Our original plan was to keep using them when we made the switch to Magento later this year, but have decided to go a different route due to 1) BorderFree not having an extension for Magento like they said they would back in October and 2) we want to bring that portion of our business in house to eliminate the fees they charge us.  I've found a few extension that will handle currency conversions and different international taxes, but haven't be able to find anything that will allow us to exclude a product to specific countries (due to that country's import restrictions).  Can anyone recommend an extension (if one exists) that will allow us to, at the product level, disable shipping to specific countries?

Using EE 1.13.0.2

Comment: did you ever find one for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of extensions that will restrict shipping based on product/country mix, we have one called ProductMatrix.  The other way to do this is to have different store views per country, which is what a lot of retailers do, in this way you prevent the products even showing in the first place.